# How to reach "My.Application" in a WPF application?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I had a WPF application where I call 
`My.Application` to check its `My.Application.Info.Version`

But now I needed to show the GUI in another WPF project, createt an new WPF project and included my existing WPF class. Now the error occours:

> Das Objekt des Typs  OUTPUT_ _ICAO_WPF.Application  kann nicht in Typ 
>   DSP_ _MaskSelektor_WPF.Application  umgewandelt werden.

Which means: Cannot cast from WPF application number one into the WPF application of target.

is there a solution to not overwrite the "old" WPF project (not change the old project) because I want to include the "old" class in several other applications as child. I would like to have an check or casting globally to get the version.

Thanks kindfully for any help
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that My.Application actually consists of the following automatically generated code:

```
        Return CType(Global.System.Windows.Application.Current, Application)
```

Where `Application` is an automatically generated class in your project's namespace.

This means that if you call `My.Application` in Project_2 from Project_1, you will receive a casting error. This is because `System.Windows.Application.Current` will return Project_1, but since the method is being executed in Project_2, the data type is `Project_2.Application`, which cannot be cast to `Project_1.Application`.

There is, however, an easy fix: add a method to Project_2 to return the version of the current assembly. The way that I usually approach this is to create a static/shared class in the assembly as follows:

```
Public Class Version
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Value() As System.Version
        Get
            Return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType(Version)).GetName.Version()
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

This works because we get the type of the Version class within the Project_2 assembly, then get the assembly details and return the System.Version from the assembly.

Then, in Project_1, you can get the version by calling `Project_2.Version.Value`.

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Ok. sounds all like the truth. I hoped there was a existing solution from Microsoft to reflect the wanted application. It works now, but it needs a wrapper for every request of Application properties! Thanks for your good explanation!!